# removal of grub boot loader from dual boot with windows 10

Tags: grub2

I am not able to remove grub bootloader from dual boot windows 10. I have tried windows 10 recovery drive method, It didn't work. I have tried bootrec.exe/fixmbr also but it didn't worked even.I am still able to see grub loader in bios settings.What to do?

Comment: Any factory installed Windows 10 is in UEFI mode. Applying fixes (fixmbr) for legacy (BIOS) installation won't work. This suggests at least Windows is indeed in UEFI mode. As such all you need to do is to make Windows boot manager first priority again, at Windows setting. Otherwise please edit and update your question with hardware specs and whether or not you explicitly installed Windows 10 in legacy mode - procedures differ a lot -, in which case the fix you tried should have worked but either way off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you will need a windows installation cd/dvd/liveUSB
put it in your optical drive/ USB drive and boot from it
on the installation screen where it asks you to install windows, click on Repair Your Computer on the lower left corner of your screen
Now go to command prompt (It probably will show a window saying "Trying to repair windows automatically", close it) and type bootrec. /fixmbr
after it finishes GRUB is gone and you can now boot into windows directly
you have an Ubuntu partition left in your computer, that doesn't show in "My Computer", to access that, right click on "My Computer" and Select "Manage" and go to "Disk Management"
Select the Ubuntu partition and format it to a file system that windows can use.

If this doesn't solve you problem and you've tried this then please explain your question throughly.